# Batch - accept input in a specifc pattern

Tags: batch-file, pattern-matching

I am working on a batch file that will need to ask users for a version. The version should take the form of `/d+/d+/d+`, bu I am anticipating that someone will mistype or deliberately give bad input. Instead of having the file try to use this incorrect pattern, I was wondering if here were some way I could set a  pattern for the input. I don't believe batch accepts reg-ex. But is there some way, an existing utility perhaps, to test input against a pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `FINDSTR` command to do basic regular expression matches.

Examples:

```
ECHO Test | FINDSTR /R /C:"[0-9]"
--> Empty/null output since it doesn't match the expression.

ECHO 132 | FINDSTR /R /C:"[0-9]"
--> 132
```

To use as validation, something like this could be done:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN (`ECHO "%InputValue%" ^| FINDSTR /R /C:"[0-9]"`) DO SET Result=%%A
IF NOT "%Result%"=="" (
    ECHO Matched the pattern.
) ELSE (
    ECHO Did not match the pattern.
)
```